# Get session change events in .Net core windows desktop service

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, desktop

I am developing a windows desktop service in .Net core 5.0 using C#. I am using hostbuilder to configureservice like

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            }).UseWindowsService();
```

How can I get session change notifications like logon, logoff... in this service?